# How Do I Remove Azure Git Push History?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I accidentally committed with the wrong credentials to git in Azure DevOps.

To fix it I ran `git filter-branch` and force pushed.

However, when I look in the Azure DevOps gui it says:

```
Authored On
Committed On
Pushed On
```

When I click on "Pushed On" it shows the refs that were updated and allows me to see the original commit with my old credentials in it.

I suspect that Azure DevOps is getting this from the reflog.

Is there any way to delete this extra information?

Can you expire the reflog on the server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There (currently) doesn't appear to be a way unless you delete the repo and push your modified version back to a new repo of the same name.

A similar question has been answered in this case on the [Azure Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/470604/commits-deleted-from-git-history-are-still-visible.html).

In his words:

> Because git is distributed, once you check in a sensitive info, you
>   should assume it is compromised and change it. Anyone could clone the
>   repository or access the commit without your knowledge within that
>   time frame. We don't garbage collect our commit data, so you are
>   correct that you can get to a commit within the system after it has
>   been "deleted". We don't provide a way to delete commits permanently
>   in Azure DevOps.